Get Type of the Class from an instance
Is there a way to get the type of the class from an instance of the object from the same class?
Like that:
template <class T>
class A {
public:
    static int value;
    using ClassType = A<T>;

    auto getSelfType(){
        return ClassType;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    A<int> j;

    j.getSelfType()::value = 12;

    return 0;
}


decltype(j)::value = 12;?

@RemyLebeau, there is no such metaprogramming mechanism in c++ at all?

Maybe explain the actual use case?

Seems like an overly complicated way of writing j.value = 12;.

Also seems like a complicated way of writing j.ClassType::value = 12; (which is itself a complicated way of writing j.value = 12;). Why do you want a function that returns a type (which is not a thing in C++, but if it was)?

A function can't return a type, like you are attempting.  It can only return a value of a specified type. So return ClassType; makes no sense.
You can, however, use decltype to get the type of a variable, eg:
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    A<int> j;

    decltype(j)::value = 12;

    return 0;
}

Online Demo
However, you don't actually need this, because you can access static members via an instance, just like with non-static members, eg:
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    A<int> j;

    j.value = 12;
    // same as:
    // A<int>::value = 12;

    return 0;
}

Online Demo

It seem you want to declare a variable of the same type. In that case use decltype:
A<int> a;
decltype(a) b; // same as: A<int> b;


no, i mean using the type itself, it is not about creating a new instance of the same type

@Max What do you mean "using the type itself". That doesn't make sense to me. Do you mean to access a static member of the type? In that case, you don't need to j.value is fine.

i mean what i mean, bruh....
